# Convert image to array and show again it in image

Tags: image, matlab

I'm using the following code to show an image from array which previously converted to array. But the image not show correctly:

```
I = imread('ut.jpg');
image=mat2gray(I);
imshow(image);
FID = fopen('FileName.txt', 'w');
if FID == -1, error('Cannot create file.'); end
fprintf(FID, '%g  %g  %g ... %g \n', image);
fclose(FID);
x = 100*rand(512,1500);
fileID = fopen('FileName.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%f',x);
fclose(fileID);
imshow(x);
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see and what do you see? Have you tried `imshow(x,[])` instead to enable auto-scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps consist of two things. First: 3 matrices with colour intensities, graduated as `uint`, numbers from 0 to 255. Second: A header containing information regarding size, colordepth, filelength, etc.

Your program does not create correct images because it misses a header.

Regarding the matlab procedure:

By using `imread` on a RGB image, you are automatically creating a matrix. If you convert it to grayscale with `rgb2gray` you will have a single matrix of `uint` (without any additional layers).

If you want to safe your image after processing it simply use:

```
I = imread('ut.jpg');

% Convert, do smth e.g. I_new = rgb2gray(I);

filename = 'myNewImage.jpg';
imwrite(I_new,filename);
```

By using `imwrite` you automatically create a correct header.